# Can't get rid of some error page which shows up while using asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-asyncio

I'm trying to extract the address of different properties using some links I already have in a text file. I've created this script using asyncio library. The script is doing fine until it encounters this type of [page](https://www.bcassessment.ca/Property/Error/?id=14e53e71-11b1-4f5e-a88c-f8a4721de99e) thrown by that site. I also checked implementing proxies but no luck. Although it certainly is not a captcha page, I end up getting that page after few requests while using asyncio. FYI, when I go for requests module, I don't encounter that page.

> How can I get rid of that error page?

Here are few of the [urls](https://pastebin.com/avpiv1yw) that I'm using in the text file.

I've tried with:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import random
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

async def get_text(session,url):
    async with session.get(url,ssl=False) as resp:
        assert resp.status == 200
        print("----------",str(resp.url))
        if "Error" in str(resp.url):raise
        return await resp.read()

async def get_info(sem,session,link):
    async with sem:
        r = await get_text(session,link)          
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r,"html.parser")
        try:
            address = soup.select_one("h1#mainaddresstitle").get_text(strip=True)
        except AttributeError: address = ""
        print(address)

async def main():
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(5)
    with open("link_list.txt","r") as f:
        link_list = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
        
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(timeout=aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=10)) as session:
        await asyncio.gather(
            *(get_info(sem,session,item) for item in link_list)
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

PS when the script crosses the rate limit, it is supposed to encounter some page like `/Property/UsageValidation` but not
`/Property/Error/?id=14e53e71-11b1-4f5e-a88c-f8a4721de99e`

Comment: I would guess you are getting rate limited at some level since you only get those pages when you make all of the requests asynchronously.  What exactly do you want your script to do when it encounters that page? Retry the request?

Comment: I don't wanna encounter that page in the first place as I don't see that page while using requests. I've already mentioned that I still come across that page even when I implement proxies. So,I highly doubt it's because of rate limit. Btw, the site starts throwing captchas when it doesn't like any bot.

Comment: You're being ratelimited.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried reproducing your issue(s), by copying a bunch of times the same urls you've shared to a source file. By doing this, I wanted to imitate a crawl of a larger set of distinct urls. Here's what I've learned.

- It looks like you *do* get rate-limited. At least I do with the code you posted.
- The `UsageValidation` page pops up even if I use a VPN or proxies.
- I've tried limiting the connections per host and/or total number of connections, to no avail.
- Putting a delay between co-routines just prolongs the time before I hit the `UsageValidation` wall. Note, I keep hitting the same urls over and over again, so this might not be representative.

Here's the code that I've managed to get the most successful responses with:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,pl;q=0.8",
}


async def get_text(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as resp:
        assert resp.status == 200
        print("----------", resp.url)
        return await resp.read()


async def get_info(sem, session, link):
    async with sem:
        r = await get_text(session, link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")
        try:
            address = soup.select_one("h1#mainaddresstitle").get_text(strip=True)
            await asyncio.sleep(2)
        except AttributeError:
            address = ""
        print(address)


async def main():
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(2)
    conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit_per_host=2, limit=2)

    with open("source.txt") as f:
        link_list = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(
            connector=conn,
            headers=headers,
            timeout=aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=5),
    ) as session:
        await asyncio.gather(
            *(get_info(sem, session, item) for item in link_list)
        )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

#### Ideas and Solutions:

- Stop hammering this (or any other) website with dozens or even hundreds of concurrent requests. Why? Because, in essence, what you're doing is a [DoS attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack), since you try to connect as fast and as often as possible to the server.
- By sharing the code on SO, it becomes a [distributed denial-of-service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack#Distributed_DoS). For huge services, like LinkedIn or Facebook, this might be hardly noticeable, but for smaller servers this might be dangerous. Having said that, even the big guys have strict anti-scraping policies and mitigation techniques.
- Wait at least one second before sending another request. The desired pause might be defined as `Crawl-delay` in `robots.txt`, but that you already know, judging by your name here.
- Remove multi-threading or at least limit the number of threads.
- Don't hit a url again and again if you've already visited it. Do your job once, but do it well.
- Write a slow, sequential crawler / scraper with a retry policy. Why? Because,  the primary goal of your crawler / scraper code should be to stay under the radar. It's better to do it slowly *and* get the job done rather than fail miserably after a couple of requests and/or getting your IP banned ultimately.
- If there's an API, use the API.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and suggestion @baduker. Using the script above, I get results accordingly until a link containing `/Property/Error/` comes across. Once that error link comes into play, I can't get rid of it by any means. The link containing `/Property/UsageValidation` is not a problem to bypass which I was able to do in the first place. I only mentioned about this link `UsageValidation` as a reply to the comment I got.