# Can't get rid of a problematic page even when using rotation of proxies within scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I've created a script using scrapy implementing rotation of proxies within it to parse the `address` from few hundreds of similar links like [this](https://www.bcassessment.ca//Property/Info/QTAwMDAwMDAyRg==). I've supplied those links from a csv file within the script.

The script is doing fine until it encounters any response url like this `https://www.bcassessment.ca//Property/UsageValidation`. Given that once the script starts getting that link, it can't bypass that. FYI, I'm using  meta properties containing `lead_link` to make use of original link instead of redirected link as a retry, so I should be able to bypass that barrier.

It doesn't happen when I use proxies within requests library. To be clearer - while using requests library, the script does encounter this page `/Property/UsageValidation` but bypass that successfully after few retries.

The spider is like:

```
class mySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "myspider"

    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': {
            'stackoverflow_spider.middlewares.ProxiesMiddleware': 100,
        }
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        with open("output_main.csv","r") as f:
            reader = csv.DictReader(f)
            for item in list(reader):
                lead_link = item['link']
                yield scrapy.Request(lead_link,self.parse,meta={"lead_link":lead_link,"download_timeout":20}, dont_filter=True)

    def parse(self,response):
        address = response.css("h1#mainaddresstitle::text").get()
        print(response.meta['proxy'],address)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT':'Mozilla/5.0',
        'LOG_LEVEL':'ERROR',
    })
    c.crawl(mySpider)
    c.start()
```

***How can I let the script not to encounter that page?***

PS I've attached few of the links within a [text file](https://filebin.net/tovu09z405oh1dfx) in case anyone wants to give a try.

Comment: This looks oddly similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64145809/cant-get-rid-of-some-error-page-which-shows-up-while-using-asyncio/64182790?noredirect=1#comment113497318_64182790). Do you guys know each other?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the solution I'm expecting using scrapy here @baduker? I came across your lined post two days back and tried to solve it but unfortunately failed. However, I thought of solving it using scrapy but no luck, so I created this post to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like the site doesn't really want to be scraped, which is totally justified, as we can see here, you're not the first one to attempt this. If it works with `requests` then maybe it's a good idea to stick to it. As I've stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64182790/6106791) the primary objective of scraping is to stay under the radar.

Comment: As requests library can do it, what's wrong with scrapy? And that is the very reason why I'm interested in it to seek a solution. Moreover, I don't encounter both of the errors the other post does. Thanks.

Comment: For proxy pool implementation in `requests` you probably set `proxy` for each `requests.Session` object. Hovewer scrapy application with default settings will use single session `cookieJar` object` for all proxies.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it @Georgiy. Nope, I didn't use session while implementing proxies in requests. When I used session in requests, I got the same problem as scrapy does at this moment. So, I stuck to requests without session instead. In my current implementation, I used `concurrent.futures` library along with requests to make the script use same working proxy multiple times until invalid which also resembles what scrapy is doing here.

Comment: It seems you could understand the problem. Is there any way I can use individual session in each requests in scrapy @Georgiy? Thanks.

Comment: If I try like [this](https://pastebin.com/cbfTAWHf), will it create individual session in each requests @Georgiy?

Comment: Hi @Georgiy, it seems your one-liner comment about session has made my day. The issue is now resolved. I'm eagerly waiting for you to write an answer at least with the comment that you made. Btw, ain't I doing in the right way in the rectified portion within the script attached? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @baduker, it seems the issue might be resolved using individual session in your linked answer. I'm not sure if it is possible to do so when it comes to implement the same in asyncio. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make session safe proxy implementation for scrapy app You
need to add additional `cookiejar` meta key to place where you assign proxy to `request.meta` like this:

```
....
yield scrapy.Request(url=link, meta = {"proxy":address, "cookiejar":address})
```

In this case scrapy `cookiesMiddleware` will create additional cookieSession for each proxy.

related specifics of scrapy proxy implementation mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64160330/10884791)

Comment: In my current implementation I found it working [this way](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#std:reqmeta-cookiejar).